# Dataframe merge in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, merge, data-manipulation

I am currently trying to perform some data manipulation procedures and collect the results in the most efficient way in terms of resources consumption.

I have to work with 3 dataframes:

**The first one:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType
data = [
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-06-06", 10, "2022-06-10"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-06-13", 20, "2022-06-15"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-06-16", 25, "2022-06-20"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-06-30", 30, "2022-07-15"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-07-18", 10, "2022-07-20"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-07-30", 20, "2022-07-31"),
    ("B", "ID2", "2022-06-15", 10, "2022-06-20"),
    ("B", "ID2", "2022-06-22", 20, "2022-06-30"),
    ("C", "ID3", "2022-06-05", 90, "2022-06-10"),
    ("C", "ID3", "2022-06-12", 95, "2022-06-15")
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ContractDate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("LoanSum", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("ClosingDate", StringType(), True)
    ])
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.withColumn("ContractDate", f.to_date("ContractDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df = df.withColumn("ClosingDate", f.to_date("ClosingDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

**The second one:**

```py
data2 = [
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-08-01", 22, None),
    ("B", "ID2", "2022-07-04", 25, None)
]

schema2 = StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ContractDate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("LoanSum", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("ClosingDate", StringType(), True)
    ])
    
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2)

df2 = df2.withColumn("ContractDate", f.to_date("ContractDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df2 = df2.withColumn("ClosingDate", f.to_date("ClosingDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

**And finally the third one:**

```py
data3 = [
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-08-03", 24, None),
    ("C", "ID3", "2022-06-17", 98, None)
]


schema3 = StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ContractDate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("LoanSum", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ClosingDate", StringType(), True)
    ])
    
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(data3, schema3)

df3 = df3.withColumn("ContractDate", f.to_date("ContractDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df3 = df3.withColumn("ClosingDate", f.to_date("ClosingDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

**My goals are:**

1. To merge two tables (df2 and df3) in a way that if these two tables include the same ID (in my example ID1), the sum of LoanSum fields of these loans should be returned and all the rows with this ID should be deleted from df2;

Expected result:

```
22 #This is a LoanSum of the row ("A", "ID1", "2022-08-01", 22, None)
```

2. After the first step is completed: merge dataframe df with dataframe df2 given the fact that merged table should include lines where each subsequent record is behind the previous one by a maximum of 6 days (using ContractDate field) and by an amount greater than the previous one (using LoanSum field).

In order to do this I use this code:

```py
df_u = df.union(df2)

cols = df_u.columns
w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("ContractDate")

df_u_1 = df_u.withColumn("PCD", f.lag("ClosingDate").over(w)) \
.withColumn("PLS", f.lag("LoanSum").over(w)) \
.withColumn("Target", f.expr("datediff(ContractDate, PCD) >= 1 and datediff(ContractDate, PCD) < 6 and LoanSum - PLS > 0")) \
.withColumn("Target", f.col("Target") | f.lead("Target").over(w)) \
.filter("Target == True")
```

The result:

```
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+----------+----+------+
|Name| ID|ContractDate|LoanSum|ClosingDate|       PCD| PLS|Target|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+----------+----+------+
|   B|ID2|  2022-06-15|     10| 2022-06-20|      null|null|  true|
|   B|ID2|  2022-06-22|     20| 2022-06-30|2022-06-20|  10|  true|
|   B|ID2|  2022-07-04|     25|       null|2022-06-30|  20|  true|
|   C|ID3|  2022-06-05|     90| 2022-06-10|      null|null|  true|
|   C|ID3|  2022-06-12|     95| 2022-06-15|2022-06-10|  90|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-06-06|     10| 2022-06-10|      null|null|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-06-13|     20| 2022-06-15|2022-06-10|  10|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-06-16|     25| 2022-06-20|2022-06-15|  20|  true|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+----------+----+------+
```

But in terms of final results I need to calculate only the LoanSum of rows that were merged from dataframe df2 and than delete all the merged rows from dataframe df and dataframe df2.

Expected result:

```
25 #This is a LoanSum of the row ("B", "ID2", "2022-07-04", 25, None)
```

3. And finally after the first and second steps are completed: merge dataframe df with dataframe df3 given the fact that merged table should include lines where each subsequent record is behind the previous one by a maximum of 6 days (using ContractDate field) and by an amount greater than the previous one (using LoanSum field).

Again in order to do this I use this code:

```py
df_u_2 = df.union(df3)

cols = df_u_2.columns
w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("ContractDate")


df_u_3 = df_u_2.withColumn("PCD", f.lag("ClosingDate").over(w)) \
.withColumn("PLS", f.lag("LoanSum").over(w)) \
.withColumn("Target", f.expr("datediff(ContractDate, PCD) >= 1 and datediff(ContractDate, PCD) < 6 and LoanSum - PLS > 0")) \
.withColumn("Target", f.col("Target") | f.lead("Target").over(w)) \
.filter("Target == True")
```

The result:

```
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+----------+----+------+
|Name| ID|ContractDate|LoanSum|ClosingDate|       PCD| PLS|Target|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+----------+----+------+
|   C|ID3|  2022-06-05|     90| 2022-06-10|      null|null|  true|
|   C|ID3|  2022-06-12|     95| 2022-06-15|2022-06-10|  90|  true|
|   C|ID3|  2022-06-17|     98|       null|2022-06-15|  95|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-06-06|     10| 2022-06-10|      null|null|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-06-13|     20| 2022-06-15|2022-06-10|  10|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-06-16|     25| 2022-06-20|2022-06-15|  20|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-07-30|     20| 2022-07-31|2022-07-20|  10|  true|
|   A|ID1|  2022-08-03|     24|       null|2022-07-31|  20|  true|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+----------+----+------+
```

But in terms of final results I need to calculate only the LoanSum of rows that were merged from dataframe df.

Expected result:

```
260
```

I can do it by myself using a lot of operations that include subtraction of dataframes but it leads to extremely slow calculations that consume all my resources.

Is it possible somehow to automate this algorithm?